# Stripe-Signature header missing with AWS API Gateway + Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I have an AWS API Gateway connected to a Lambda that listens for Stripe webhooks on checkout.

[image]

Here is another screen:
[image]

When I checkout with test credentials, I get 400 Bad Request "Webhook Error: No stripe-signature header value was provided."

I am confused because I thought HTTP forwarded all headers even if they are not explicitly mapped.  I'm not sure what to do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the incorrect webhook secret configured in your webhook handler. Visit this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#endpoint-secrets) for more

Comment: The STRIPE_SECRET_KEY and STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET (Signing secret) are both correct. I just double checked.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same error. After doing some debugging I noticed that the header casing was not matching my code.

I use Node.js, so I was used to `req.headers["stripe-signature"]`, however when I logged `req.headers` I saw `'Stripe-Signature'`. So, maybe it is a header casing issue? It was for me.

I ended up doing this in Node.js:

```js
const headersMap = new Map(Object.entries(req.headers).map(([key, value]) => [key.toLowerCase(), value]));
const sig = headersMap.get("stripe-signature");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Lambda looks something like this

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export const handler = async (event) => {
    const rawBody = event.isBase64Encoded ? Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64').toString() : event.body;
    const sigHeader = event.headers['Stripe-Signature'] || event.headers['stripe-signature'];

    try {
        const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            rawBody,
            sigHeader,
            process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
        );

        // Process the event
        console.log('Successfully processed Stripe webhook:', stripeEvent.type);
        
        // Respond to Stripe to acknowledge receipt of the webhook
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ received: true }),
        };
```

Doing

```
const sigHeader = event.headers['Stripe-Signature'] || event.headers['stripe-signature'];
```

will make sure case-sensitiveness won't impact you.

Then all you need to do is make sure the `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` and `STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET` are properly defined in your Lambda environment variables configuration

[image]

Contrary to what people may think, the value for `STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET` is the one marked in the following image with the name `Signing secret`

[image]